# Android - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android, xml, illegalstateexception

I looked at a lot of posts with the same title, but everyone seems to have different solutions. I don't get an errors in Eclipse when it saves and compiles.

we don't want logcat. we want succcess cast. this problem what's the problem?? if you know. would please tell me why??

**Register.java**

```
    package com.example.tab;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Register extends Activity {     

    String myId, myPassword, myEmail, myResult; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
    }

    public void RegisterClicked(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_register:
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        myId = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.registerName))).getText().toString();  
        myPassword = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.registerPassword))).getText().toString();  
        myEmail = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.registerEmail))).getText().toString();  

        httpPostData();
        }
    }
    public void httpPostData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/register.php");    
                      HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    

                      http.setDefaultUseCaches(false);                                            
                      http.setDoInput(true);                          
                      http.setDoOutput(true);                         
                      http.setRequestMethod("POST");          
                      http.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 

                      buffer.append("id").append("=").append(myId).append("&");   
                      buffer.append("password").append("=").append(myPassword).append("&");   
                      buffer.append("email").append("=").append(myEmail).append("&");
                      OutputStreamWriter outStream = new OutputStreamWriter(http.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"); 
                      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream); 
                      writer.write(buffer.toString()); 
                      writer.flush();

                      InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");  
                      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp); 
                      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
                      String str; 

                      while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {        
                           builder.append(str + "\n");                     
                      } 
                 } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 

                 } catch (IOException e) { 

                 } 
        }
}
```

**register.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3b3b3b" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >
        <!--  View Title Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--  Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />
        <!--  Name TextField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!--  Email Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email" />
        <!--  Email TextField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!--  Password Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Password" />
        <!--  Password TextField -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true" />

        <!--  Error message -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/register_error"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#e30000"
                    android:paddingTop="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <!--  Login Button -->       
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:onClick="RegisterClicked" 
            android:text="Register" />

        <!--  Link to Login Screen -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToLoginScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Already registred. Login Me!"
            android:textColor="#21dbd4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**My Logcat**

```
  06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at            android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  ... 11 more
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at com.example.tab.Register.httpPostData(Register.java:65)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  at com.example.tab.Register.RegisterClicked(Register.java:40)
   06-02 04:46:56.694: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):  ... 14 more
   06-02 04:46:56.940: E/Trace(2420): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

**AndroidManifast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tab.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".MyTabActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".pants10_1Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoMainFragment" />
        <activity
            android:name=".shirt10_1Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TabMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Logout" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. use thread or AsyncTask. No Network operation on the main ui thread

Answer (score 0):

You can't run network IO on the main thread.  You need to run it in an AsyncTask or Thread.